# TLC5940NT + 12v 5050 led strip

Tags: microcontroller, led, transistors, resistors, integrated-circuit

**I'm trying to figure out if i could use 16 white 5cm 12v 5050 led strip with the TLC5940**

The Array/paralell setup on the strip is something like this:

```
+12V    
+   -|>|-   -|>|-   -|>|-   -/\/\/\-    +   R = 150 ohms
+   -|>|-   -|>|-   -|>|-   -/\/\/\-    +   R = 150 ohms
+   -|>|-   -|>|-   -|>|-   -/\/\/\-    +   R = 150 ohms
```

[image]

Using the http://led.linear1.org/led.wiz to calculate the values i came up with this:

- each 150 ohm resistor dissipates 43.35 mW the wizard thinks 1/4W
- all resistors dissipate 130.05 mW together
- the diodes dissipate 489.6 mW total
- power dissipated by the array is 619.65 mW
- the array draws current of 51 mA from the source.

*This is probably correct as with a regulated 12v led driver i measured 15cm and it was around 120-130mA*

The TLC is able to sink 120mA (with a proper heatsink).

So i guess that it could handle 51mA..... but it's at 12v

Reading  the [TLC's datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf) and the following post http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=143539.0 i probably found what i need.

> At 120mA a 15 Ohm resistor will swallow 1.8V.
>
> So...if the LED takes 2.4V, the resistor takes 1.8V, that leaves 0.8V
>   for the TLC5940.
>
> 0.8V*120mA*16=1.536W total dissipation - that's within spec.

and

> My LED's use 3.2V at 120mA so 5V-3.2V = 1.8V.... 1.8V * 120mA ==
>   0.216W per channel. 2.5W/ 0.216W = 11.57 ..... So I can run 11 of these LED's.

```
So: 


9.6v (3x3.2v) @ 51mA so 12v-9.6v = 2.4v * 51mA = 122.4mW * 16channels = 1,958W.
```

**"2.0 Watt on the TLC5940NT" is this calculation correct?**

**Do i need a heatsink for 2 watt on the TLC5940?**

The TLC5940NT is nice because you just need one resistor to impose the resistance on all leds. but as on those 5cm strips the resistors are already soldered in place **what should i put on the iref pin (20)? no resistor ? to ground? a small resistor?**

---

**IF the above does not work**

Most examples using transistors and mosfets to increase the wattage use PNP / P-type transistors. While the official datasheet suggests NPN transistors or N-Type Mosfets.

[Using TLC5940 With Higher LED Supply Voltages and Series LEDs](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva280/slva280.pdf)

Using NPN transsistors it's probably inverted at the end.... but more efficent ... right?
But also with PNP transistors it's inverted right?
**Why are there more examples with PNP transistors?**

If the above calculation is correct i probably need to use transistors.

The mosfets i own are all n-type but i have not enough power to fully saturate each mosfet considering 5v . so i think i go for transiostors.
i have some p2n2222a NPN. those can sink 500mA each.. that should allow me to not overheat my circuit. this also would allow me to use 15cm per channel.

**In that case how should i setup the TLC5940NT?**
Looking at the TI pdf it looks suspicious that the emitter goes directly to the ground.
it says that using an NPN allows to do all the math based on the transistor, so it would actually be able to sink 500mA(with proper heatsink on NPN)?
Vcc comes from 5v or 12v? and what resistor should i put at the base of the npn?

Comment: 5cm sounds big.

Comment: The calculations leave me a bit confused. At one point it says "with a regulated 12v led driver i measured 15cm and it was around 120-130mA". So is that the current through a 3 or 9 LED 'segment'? Then the calculations talk about 51mA. Where did that figure come from? At one point the LEDs use 3.2V at 120mA, then at another 2.4V. Which is it? A one point the resistor is 150ohm, at another 15ohm. Is that picture the strip you are using? The picture shows SMD resistors marked "151" which is 150ohm. If the voltage is 12V, then a 150ohm resistor would immediately limit the current to 80mA anyway.

Comment: yes 9 led segment = 120mA, 51mA is for a 3 led segment calculated automatically by  http://led.linear1.org/led.wiz just put in the correct values.most white leds are 3.2v-3.6v. 2.4v is the excess of the 12 v considering 3 5050leds leds.no not 80 , 51mA

Comment: http://www.synergy21.de/fileadmin/transfer/products/76956.pdf

Comment: each led has 3 cathodes and 3 anodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two TLC5940, and only use half the OUT pins by only connecting 8 LED arrays to each TLC5940. Connect the TLC5940's in series, and so there is no extra pins needed to drive the TLC5940s.

Then for the power calculations, the power dissipation is halved.

That [datasheet](http://www.synergy21.de/fileadmin/transfer/products/76956.pdf) for the LEDs says the worst case (lowest) voltage drop is 3V.

So, 3 LEDs is a series 'string' 3x3V = 9v
Resistor voltage drop = 12V-9V = 3V
current = 3V/150Ω = 0.02A (20mA)
Three parallel set of three series strings = 0.06A (60mA)
16 sets of 0.06A strings is 0.96A  (960mA)

Looking at the graphs in the [TLC5940 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf), its voltage drop for a 60mA current could be under 1V (Figure 5 and 6), which will reduce the current, but yields a worst case power dissipation of:
0.96A x <1V = < 0.96W (about 1W)

The PDIP package's thermal impedance of 48°C/W, so 1W raises its temperature by 48C.

The maximum operating temperature is 85C, so that might be a bit tight if the electronics are inside a box, but maybe okay if it is exposed to the air, operated it in an office (e.g. with air conditioning).

The other packages have better thermal characteristics, so you could design a PCB, and use them. However, if this is for a small number of systems, it might be as easy to use two PDIP TLC5940s and get more headroom.

EDIT:
Remember, the total light output from an LED will be reduced if it is being multiplexed because it is only on for a fraction of the time. So multiplexing may not be a useful option. If it is a useful option, because the LEDs do not need to be fully powered all of the time, then the TLC5940 could probably drive the LEDs directly, running at a lower PWM cycle than full-on, and hence needing to dissipate less heat, anyway.

The thing that destroys semiconductor electronics is temperature, not just power.

So even if the spec says the TLC5940 will handle the power, it might still malfunction if it gets too hot. If it were enclosed in a box, the ambient temperature would rise, and even though the TLC5940 PDIP can dissipate 1W for a 48C temperature rise, inside a box heated to 40C, and it is operating beyond the recommended spec.

If the TLC5940 runs above its recommended 85C maximum, it will fail much more quickly. A high enough temperature might even damage it (I have used older parts with 'thermal protection' but they have still been destroyed by overheating). Even if the chip's thermal protection works, the effect may be to reduce the brightness of the lights, so trying to run it too hot may be self defeating.

So, as long as it is cooled enough, then even the PDIP TLC5940 (its worst package for thermal dissipation) should be able to handle 1W without the temperature rise reaching 85C.

Personally, I would try to do some experiments to get some actual data. The calculations indicate it should work fine, but actual conditions are a real factor to consider. Superb heat sinks but an ambient of 40C might still affect the life of the part.

You could easily limit the current below this level, if the light output is adequate, and hence reduce the heat generated, lowering the temperature of the part. The TLC5940 makes this straightforward; adjust the single 'programming' resistor on the TLC5940. So it should be a safe and straightforward experiment to do. Start with a lower current, say 2/3rds what you think you need, and have a look at the results.

If a lot of light is critical, I would seriously consider offloading 20%+ of any TLC5940's load to an extra TLC5940 to give me some temperature headroom. That alone might be enough, and avoid any of the the extra complexity of trying to multiplex, or use external transistors.

END EDIT

Comment: nah, thats 5 $ per 16leds. i tried to keep the question as simple as possible even if reading it again looks very complicated. i plan to use more leds more tlc's then later multiplex... but that is another story.. using 2 tlc's for each array would also insanely increase the price of what i wanna build.so that is the worst thing i heard.To summarize my question above: is the TLC able to handle 3x 5050 leds each with a 150 ohm resistor?this on each channel.

Comment: btw its cheaper to add 16 transistors vs adding another tlc

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva280/slva280.pdf

Comment: http://www.synergy21.de/fileadmin/transfer/products/76956.pdf

Comment: So in the update your saying based on the calculations it should be able to handle a 5cm led strip x 16 with a heatsink or at least an "exposed to the air".And also my calculations are totally wrong ... so the total wattage the tlc needs to sink is only 1watt and not 2watt(my calc)?

Comment: @cocco - if the projects is to handle many more than 16 LED segments, and those LEDs will be multiplexed, please update your question to match the actual project. Otherwise we can waste time answering the wrong questions, and you'll get frustrated. If it's one-off and cost sensitive buy from ebay/aliexpress/alibaba/etc, they are under $1. Each OUT of the TLC5940 is a matched constant current source, and is not just a transistor. So if matching LED segment brightness matters, it may be more complex than your estimate. If its for many LEDs, then reduce from 16 to 12, 25% more headroom.

Comment: I'm using alot the uln2803 it says it sinks 500mA per channel, the truth is that it's able to sink around 200mA per channel without getting hot. the tlc5940 says it can sink 120mA per channel .... IS IT ABLE TO SINK THOSE 16*60mA@12v? yes no?thats the question.... i use this chip for its 4096 dimming capabilities. And if i multiplex later or add more tlc's , in that case the chips have to sink less. So the question remains always the same.IS IT ABLE TO SINK THOSE 16*60mA@12v?

Comment: i already have 4 of those chips, i payed them 6€ so much. i like the fact that i can use 4096 values for the dimming process. i also like the fact that it is constant current with one single resistor, but normal leds don't produce enough light. strips(5cm) would be better, more light.

Comment: i'm more a programmer, i like to write animations for those leds.not anelecronical enginer.but i try to find lout myself... this is alittle to complicated for me atm. thats why i'm asking here. also answering this question allows me to use other different strips as i know they consume less.like the rgb strip 5050. anyway the question is always the same. Can a tlc5940 sink 12v@60mA*16channel with those resistors. datasheet says 120mA*channel leds theoretically consume 60mA. i also can't find total Amps in the datasheet? around 2A ?? 1A?

Comment: if its ok but a heatsink is needed i can put them in a stright line and put a long piece of iron on it. as i use pwm i'm also able to set the max a little lower ... like 3584 vs 4096.. Also if i would understands the error in  my calculation.. or how to calculate the temp based on what i consume would allow me to later do some math myself. your calc says 1W the tlc should easely handle 1w... but not 2w...

Comment: basically if i understand correct, ambient temp summer= 30°C + 1W based on your calc= 30+48 = 78°C correct? what would a big piece of iron change on that chip? what about putting a resistor "for the constant current" on the tlc to limit the overall mA output? limit the output @ 50mA vs 60mA ... so having .8W vs 1W ? the temp then should be 60-70°C

Comment: i have some temp sensors & arcit silver... i could test the temp starting with pwm @ 25% duty...and then slowly rise it.to  see how hot it is going to be. 25% should be safe?

Comment: because srsly... until now i considered the tlc5940 as a superstandalone chip... but if it's not able to sink those 50-60mA than transistors/mosfets are the only solution.I'm trying to illuminate my room. thats why normal leds are not a solution, 1 led is not a solution. but a strip of 5cm produces already a nice light.

Comment: i have a square room ... so i could have a matrix of 8x8x5cm (3led) strip and that would be the equivalent of 3,2meter of that strip... nice light and considering the 64channel 4096 steps pwm would produce nice animations.

Comment: if this not works i need more ... so mosfets or transistors.in that case i could use other leds like the 5630 they consume 120mA each 5cm.more light.this is all the info i can give you.if you need to know more just ask. And really thx for your help.

Comment: @cocco - As I understand your project, you want to run 8x8 = 64 of those LED segments, correct? My bigger concern is the ambient temperature. As long as the TLC5940's are well under 85C, they should not cause any hassle. So a block of metal at 30C should be fine. I have added to may answer that a 20%+ offload might be enough, so five instead of 4 TLC5940 might be enough. Or, if you reduce the current by 20%. I'd recommend keeping the electronics simple, using only TLC5940, because debugging may be too frustrating if you have lots more components and connections to test.

Comment: i think i start measuring the temperature with the "program" resistor as limiter.Putting a 1000ohm(1kΩ) i should limit the current @ 40mA per channel, to a max of 640mA tot, max heat @25°C should be around 55°C... right? Is that correct?

Comment: another question... can i put a potentiometer + resistor as current limiting? in that case i can set it to 4095 (fullbright) and with 500Ω Resistor + 1k potentimoeter i could change the current source limit from 22mA to 60mA per channel

Comment: If a potentiometer is possible , that would be the best way to find the proper resistance to limit the whole circuit, measuring the temperature.Also to see how much light it emits.

Comment: keeping that potentiometer would also allow me to decrease the maximum output on hot days without loosing the fantastic 4096 resosultion!

Comment: @cocco - I can't see anything in the datasheet to suggest using a variable resistor, to tweak the current, will not work. So I assume it will be fine. Double check your calculation for the resistor values; I get 651 fixed (nearest 620/280).

Comment: 31.06/mA=Ω ? 31.06/0.06A=516Ω & 31.06/0.02A=1553Ω

Comment: 39.06/mA ouch .. 651Ω 1,953Ω ... right... so 650Ω resistor + 1,5kΩ pot

Comment: maybe i test with normal leds first and a 2,2k pot + 2k resistor

Comment: thank you very much for your patience. At this point everything is much clearer. i hope i get some nice results.

Comment: @cocco - Thank you. I hope everything works out well. If you do have issues, you know where we are ;-0